# MyBatis Migrations: migrate up causes org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.RuntimeSqlException

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I just installed [Mybatis Migration](https://github.com/mybatis/migrations) and followed their [instructions](http://mybatis.github.io/migrations/migrate.html). The init, new, status commands worked but "migrate up" causes the below error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MyBatis Migrations - up
------------------------------------------------------------------------
========== Applying: 20140410190604_create_changelog.sql =======================
Error executing: --  Create Changelog

-- Default DDL for changelog table that will keep
-- a record of the migrations that have been run.

-- You can modify this to suit your database before
-- running your first migration.

-- Be sure that ID and DESCRIPTION fields exist in
-- BigInteger and String compatible fields respectively.

CREATE TABLE CHANGELOG (
ID NUMERIC(20,0) NOT NULL,
APPLIED_AT VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE CHANGELOG
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CHANGELOG
PRIMARY KEY (id);

.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE CHANGELOG
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CHANGELOG
PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 18
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MyBatis Migrations FAILURE
-- Total time: 0s
-- Finished at: Thu Apr 10 15:08:51 PDT 2014
-- Final Memory: 12M/479M
------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Error executing command.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.RuntimeSqlException: Error executing: --  Create Changelog

-- Default DDL for changelog table that will keep
-- a record of the migrations that have been run.

-- You can modify this to suit your database before
-- running your first migration.

-- Be sure that ID and DESCRIPTION fields exist in
-- BigInteger and String compatible fields respectively.

CREATE TABLE CHANGELOG (
ID NUMERIC(20,0) NOT NULL,
APPLIED_AT VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE CHANGELOG
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CHANGELOG
PRIMARY KEY (id);

.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE CHANGELOG
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CHANGELOG
PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 18
```

The two mysql DDL (create table and alter table) were generated by migrations in the file 20140410190604_create_changelog.sql. However, if I manually ran the sql it didn't complain any syntax error.

What might causes this "migrate up" problem?

```
The script is like:

CREATE TABLE CHANGELOG (
ID NUMERIC(20,0) NOT NULL,
APPLIED_AT VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE CHANGELOG
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CHANGELOG
PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `send_full_script=false` in `enviornment.properties` file fixes the problem.